# Animation duration of a flutter TabBarView

Tags: animation, flutter, tabs, tabview

In Flutter I have the following issue.

I want to control the animation speed (transition duration) of a TabBarView. The content body is sliding from left to right during a TabBar click. I want this to be instantaneous. Very similar to the Twitter app with its main TabBar icon at the bottom.

Is there a way to control the animation (duration) of the TabVarView?

Answer (score 2):

You can control the general physics of the scroll animation.

```
TabBarView(
  physics: CustomTabBarViewScrollPhysics(),
```

**Control the scroll behavior:**

```
class CustomTabBarViewScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  const CustomTabBarViewScrollPhysics({ScrollPhysics? parent})
      : super(parent: parent);

  @override
  CustomTabBarViewScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) {
    return CustomTabBarViewScrollPhysics(parent: buildParent(ancestor)!);
  }

  @override
  SpringDescription get spring => const SpringDescription(
        mass: 50,
        stiffness: 100,
        damping: 0.8,
      );
}
```

You should also be able to calculate the duration with mass, stiffness, damping, but I believe having those options is even better suited for your problem. [Source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55103#issuecomment-747059541)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it direclty with a TabBar! You should create a CustomTab and add an 'Inkwell' on it. You should set the onTap parameter of the inkwell to :

```
() = tabController.animateTo(0, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 0));'
```

So it should look like that

```
Widget _buildTabItem({
  int index,
  ValueChanged<int> onPressed,
}) {
  return Expanded(
    child: Container(
      child: Material(
        type: MaterialType.transparency,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () => onPressed(index),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              /// Icon and text here
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I had a similar approach to basically build a custom app bar and handle the animateTo manually but the problem is that it is the animation duration of the TabBarView that I am trying to reduce to zero seconds. This approach does not reduce the animation of the TabBarView page transitions.

Comment: Not sure if there is a bug in Flutter but `tabController.animateTo(0, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 0));` has no effect on duration

Comment: Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55625